# How to keep Google Maps Android API v2 map loaded during Activity restart?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating a navigation app which uses Google Maps Android API v2. When the `Activity` with the map (`MapFragment`) is being started, a `PolylineOptions` (a line) and an array of `MarkerOptions`' is being added to the map.

This may take long time in some cases, so I wonder if it is possible to keep the map loaded when the `Activity` is being restarted, for example due to screen orientation change, so that I don't have to "re-add" all the markers and the line again, which may sometimes take quite some time.

Right now, I get the `MapFragment` and set its `OnMapReadyCallback` every time the activity is started, then, in the callback method, the line and markers are being added (after every restart).

Comment: Please, stop using salutations, signatures and custom formatting in your questions and answers. Stop bolding the first few words of each paragraph, and leave all the `<hr>` tags out of your posts, they are not necessary.

Comment: @meagar I do that to make it easier to read. For example, I often describe what I'm creating, then ask the question. If someone want to jump directly to the question text, it is easier to find it if the beginning is bold

Comment: Your entire question should be the question text. If there is inessential content, you should remove it.

Comment: @meagar Why do the `<hr>` tags and the formatting exist then? Aren't they meant to be used?

Comment: They are meant to be used in moderation, not abused to mark up every single paragraph in your question.